# Getting strange errors when breaking up a long number into its component integers

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is for Project Euler's 8th question, which asks you to find the greatest product of five consecutive digits in this one really long number.

My code is definitely **NOT** the most elegant solution, but I'm pretty sure it should work. And it does seem to work with small numbers, but once the number I test is greater than 16 digits, everything starts to fall apart (e.g. The subsets are getting e's and 0's and different numbers instead of the digits in the actual given number.)

```
function consecProduct(num,sec){
//converts the number to a string
var parser = num.toString();
var numLength = parser.length;
//prepares an array to hold 5 consecutive digits
var pieces = [];
var greatestProduct = 0;
var piecesTogether = 1;
// The outer loop that runs through each set of five digits
for (i=0; i<numLength-4; i++){
    //fills a string with the five digit subset
    var product = parser.substring(sec-5, sec);
    console.log("product "+product);
    //increments subset by 1
    sec++;
    //fills each array position with a each digit from subset
    for(x=0;x<5;x++){
        pieces[x]=product.substring(x,x+1);
        console.log(x + " is "+ pieces[x]);
    }
    //converts each array digit back to an integer
     for(x=0;x<5;x++){
        pieces[x]=parseInt(pieces[x]);
    }
    console.log("hey");
    //gets the product of the subset
    for(x=0;x<5;x++){
        piecesTogether = piecesTogether*pieces[x];
        console.log(pieces[x] + " work " + piecesTogether);
    }
    //updates the greatestProduct
    if ( piecesTogether > greatestProduct ){
        greatestProduct = piecesTogether;
        console.log("great product " + greatestProduct)
    }
    //resets the product for the next subset
    piecesTogether = 1;
}
return greatestProduct;
}
console.log("hey");
consecProduct(111125455578788855,5);
```

I have been testing it with Codecademy's scratchpad, maybe that is part of the problem. I just started learning js last week and only began these Euler problems yesterday, so I could be completely screwing this in a whole universe of ways. Any ideas?

Comment: Is this hoemwork? Also, what is sec?

Comment: I don't think Javascript will handle a 1000-digit number without a 3rd-party bignum library. You may want to pass the parameter as a character string instead.

Comment: No, not homework. This is just for fun. sec is a parameter of the function, to delimit the block of con(sec)utive integers. It's 5 in the [euler problem](http://projecteuler.net/problem=8).

Comment: Good idea, @Blastfurnace! That'll also save me the awkward step of converting the number to a string, which could be another source of the problem.

Comment: THAT DID IT @Blastfurnace! I love you!

Comment: Just for the record, all javascript numbers are 64-bit doubles. Some of that is the exponent, so the mantissa will only be about 54 bits, which would be around 16 or 17 digits (that's an estimation, might be off by a bit). edit: Which is why problems started popping up around 16 digits

Comment: @wds, yeah, I found the power-of-2 cutoff to be suspicious. Sadly, I don't know enough about this stuff to put that suspicion to any use. These euler problems are really great for incrementally lowering my brain into this huge, boiling vat of knowledge without completely shutting down. Mantissa and 64-bit doubles are still geek to me, however; they'll be going on my ToGoogle list. Thanks lovely people! What a fantastic site this is.

Comment: my js implementation: http://jsfiddle.net/u374T/

Comment: @KitLangton The first few sections of this explain it well, if you are interested http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you pass the digits as a string you can use your method,

but most browsers have a forEach method that can simplify it for you.

```
function eu8(s, n){
    var max= 0, last= 0, A= s.split(''), L= A.length,
    next, temp;
    A.forEach(function(itm, i, A){
        next= i;
        temp= itm;
        while(next<(i+n) && ++next<L) temp*= A[next];
        if(temp> max){
            max= temp;
            last= i;
        }
    });
    return [' Largest product in a sequence of '+n+' digits  totals '+max+
    ',\n found at digits #'+last+'-'+(last+n)+' : '+A.slice(last, last+n)];
}
// a shim for old browsers, (not needed with console):
if(!Array.prototype.forEach){
    Array.prototype.forEach= function(fun, scope){
        var T= this, L= T.length, i= 0;
        if(typeof fun== 'function'){
            while(i< L){
                if(i in T){
                    fun.call(scope, T[i], i, T);
                }
                ++i;
            }
        }
        return T;
    }
}
var s= '8383514919085125086820290424163504559356377168995032348562649291222000387486432845620761935475604819050366697920932015432273771435337266340072387705128115575935425014460947570294275818158944549440881025891661096019719598195504110300188717866666358085201663329077618987279717181749021476776048734274617619666392413744636813999541150937273597312043999174331828004915627872035802437409595473241982712379412840772356975718777505301009358387887491501687808639811743258849513533372548739871812190760522789399701735667528924543523146196411626759899045981351660803008793628326225793570101225880141881354855219845587323306406026446646995422604684079629891934580835393600990916331750430169147648113885025045982027652181257767798206409176994378464211282557774833632004180439443121563895765081630408290308927246861936209942841914894036534524282034126702443265629680626122703321065703277654006714223903324966372058553562951193965443957787594408861841150727372912209556865206484636763870595651959623483481581867874';



alert(eu8(s, 5));
//eu8(s, 5)
>>returned value:
 Largest product in a sequence of 5 digits  totals 204120,
 first found at digits #535-540 : 7,5,9,8,9
```

Comment: Oh man, that is gorgeous. I had to look up forEach() to see from where the hell those three parameters were getting their arguments. There is one thing I still can't grok: How do you increment next? Is that what ++next does? I didn't know you could do that from within a parenthetical!

Answer (score 0):

I just recently started going through Project Euler and implemented a regular for loop rather than taking the forEach method.

```
function largestProduct(n, d){
  var max = 0
  for(var i = 0; i < n.length - d; i++){
    var prod = 1;
    for(var j = 0; j < d; j++){  
      prod *= Number(n.charAt(i+j));
    }
    if(prod > max){
      max = prod;
    }
  }
  return max;
}
```